# Private Chain Self-Hosted Mist Wallet Build Issues

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, meteor

I'm currently trying to deploy a fork of the Meteor Wallet Dapp on a custom private chain and I'm a bit confused at the set up, there seems to be a bit of lacking documentation on how Mist, Meteor-Dapp-Wallet and Meteor-Build-Client work together and how the wallet.ethereum.org server is set up and it has been challenging to try and recreate it externally.

I've forked the Mist Client and did the full:

```
$ gulp
```

To build both distributions as well as:

```
$ meteor-build-client ../build --path ""
```

from within the interface folder to get my custom build folder with the index.html

Then based on the instructions here in the Meteor-Build-Client repo (https://github.com/frozeman/meteor-build-client) I've set up a server that has meteor installed, has the files from the build folder (such as index.html) in my Apache htdocs, added the required .htaccess modifications and is running a geth node with RPC enabled.

Then on my desktop I launch the Mist client that I tried to build with 'gulp' and I navigate in the browser to my site.

I think I'm missing at least one step here (in relation to connecting the html page to the meteor app on the server. It was pretty unclear where that code goes from the Meteor-Build-Client repo), and I could be missing a few other elements.

Can anyone provide some insights to the current set up of wallet.ethereum.org and the steps that would go into using these packages to recreate that setup?

Thanks for any insights!